# SQL Grouping by year gives incorrect results

Tags: sql, grouping, advantage-database-server

I am trying to summerize sales date, by month, sales region and type. The problem is, the results change when I try to group by year.

My simplified query is as follows:

```
SELECT
DAB700.DATUM,DAB000.X_REGION,DAB700.BELEG_ART, // the date, sales region, order type
   // calculate the number of orders per month
   COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(DAB700.DATUM) =  1 THEN DAB700.BELEG_NR END) as jan,
   COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(DAB700.DATUM) =  2 THEN DAB700.BELEG_NR END) as feb,
   COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(DAB700.DATUM) =  3 THEN DAB700.BELEG_NR END) as mar
FROM "DAB700.ADT" DAB700
left join "DAB050.ADT" DAB050 on DAB700.BELEG_NR = DAB050.ANUMMER // join to table 050, to pull in order info
left join "DF030000.DBF" DAB000 on DAB050.KDNR = DAB000.KDNR // join table 000 to table 050, to pull in customer info
left join "DAB055.ADT" DAB055 on DAB050.ANUMMER = left (DAB055.APNUMMER,6)// join table 055 to table 050, to pull in product info
WHERE (DAB700.BELEG_ART = 10 OR DAB700.BELEG_ART = 20) AND (DAB700.DATUM>={d '2021-01-01'}) AND (DAB700.DATUM<={d '2021-01-11'}) AND DAB055.ARTNR <> '999999' AND DAB055.ARTNR <> '999996' AND DAB055.TERMIN <> 'KW.22.22' AND DAB055.TERMIN <> 'KW.99.99' AND DAB050.AUF_ART = 0
group by DAB700.DATUM,DAB000.X_REGION,DAB700.BELEG_ART
```

This returns the following data, which is correct (manually checked):

```
| DATUM      | X_REGION | BELEG_ART | jan | feb | mar |
|------------|----------|-----------|-----|-----|-----|
| 04.01.2021 | 1        | 10        | 3   | 0   | 0   |
| 04.01.2021 | 3        | 10        | 2   | 0   | 0   |
| 04.01.2021 | 4        | 10        | 1   | 0   | 0   |
| 04.01.2021 | 4        | 20        | 1   | 0   | 0   |
| 04.01.2021 | 6        | 20        | 2   | 0   | 0   |
| 05.01.2021 | 1        | 10        | 1   | 0   | 0   |
and so on....
```

The total number of records for Jan is 117 (correct).

Now I now want to summerize the data in one row (for example, data grouped by region and type)..

so I change my code so that I have:

```
SELECT
YEAR(DAB700.DATUM),
```

and

```
group by YEAR(DAB700.DATUM)
```

the rest of the code stays the same.

Now my results are:

```
| EXPR | X_REGION | BELEG_ART | jan | feb | mar |
|------|----------|-----------|-----|-----|-----|
| 2021 | 1        | 10        | 16  | 0   | 0   |
| 2021 | 1        | 20        | 16  | 0   | 0   |
| 2021 | 2        | 10        | 19  | 0   | 0   |
| 2021 | 2        | 20        | 22  | 0   | 0   |
| 2021 | 3        | 10        | 12  | 0   | 0   |
| 2021 | 3        | 20        | 6   | 0   | 0   |
```

Visually it is correct. But, the total count for January is now 116. A difference of 1. What am I doing wrong?

How can I keep the results from the first code - but have it presented as per the 2nd set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You count **distinct** `BELEG_NR`. This is what makes the difference. Let's look at an example. Let's say your table contains four rows:

| DATUM | X_REGION | BELEG_ART | BELEG_NR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04.01.2021 | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 04.01.2021 | 1 | 10 | 200 |
| 05.01.2021 | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 05.01.2021 | 1 | 10 | 300 |

That gives you per day, region and belegart:

| DATUM | X_REGION | BELEG_ART | DISTINCT COUNT BELEG_NR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04.01.2021 | 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 05.01.2021 | 1 | 10 | 2 |

and per year, region and belegart

| YEAR | X_REGION | BELEG_ART | DISTINCT COUNT BELEG_NR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 10 | 3 |

The `BELEG_NR` 100 never appears more than once per day, so every instance gets counted. But it appears twice for the year, so it gets counted once instead of twice.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, thanks! Your explanation makes sense. I will need to check the data in detail to see if this fits. If so, what would be the solution to show unique orders per month... on the one row (per region and type)? Any tips?

Comment: Well, it seems that one `beleg_nr` can relate to more than one `datum`. So the question is: What does this mean from the business point of view? Should you count them or not? A solution might be not to count distinct at all. Or to only count the first `datum` per `beleg_nr`. Or to count distinct `datum` + `beleg_nr`... I cannot answer this of course.

Comment: ah good idea - I think selecting the first date, for any beleg_nr is the best solution, and then counting those... I'll mark the question as answered!